# How to register as a part time freelancer

Tags: taxes, registration, spain

I am a Belgian citizen residing in Spain where I already have a full time job and would like to do some freelance work after hours.

- Do I need to register in Spain?
- What are my possibilities concerning income and social security taxes?
- I heard of this possibility of becoming a freelancer on "European level" which would mean I wouldn't pay social security taxes in Spain. Could you please tell me more about this?

Comment: What information have you researched so far? Who told you about becoming a freelancing on the Europian level? Did they have any documentation about that?

Comment: As far as I am aware, despite the *Single European Market* there is no such thing as freelancing on a *European Level* - the rules about taxation and especially social taxes are very opaque, and I commend proper legal and/or accounting advice!

Comment: Dear all, thank you for your replies. The reason I asked is because last year we got a legislation training at work given by a former lawyer.He has mentioned this European Level but since i couldn't find anything about it on the internet I thought I would try here. It's so hard to find your way in these cobwebs called legislation.

Comment: "I already have a full time job". First thing to check is that your current job contract allows for work on the side.

Answer (score 2):

Full time freelancer living in Spain here. You must register as an "*Autonomo*" after you reach the top of selling professional services, more or less 2000€ for unemployed people last time I checked it.

Check if your contract allows it.

It may vary depending on the "*Comunidad Autonoma*" in which you are living or your work, so go to "*Seguridad Social*" and ask for selling "*Servicios Profesionales*".

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think noone here can answer your question because it is a very complicated task that involves local, national and international laws.

You shoud definitely go to a professional accountant to have all the answers tailored for your situation.